Pre-redirect and pipes: >file (cmd1 | cmd2)
In bash, how can I put a redirection before a command that contains a pipe?
cmd1 >file           # bash is happy
>file cmd1           # bash is happy
cmd1 | cmd2 >file    # bash is happy
>file cmd1 | cmd2    # bash is happy but cmd2 and I are not
(cmd1 | cmd2) >file  # bash is happy
>file (cmd1 | cmd2)  # syntax error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>file {cmd1 | cmd2;} # syntax error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

For the xy-background, I need to redirect a bunch of long ugly commands to different files and it's a lot more readable to put these files first.
Something like:
>file1 command1 --with --lots --of arguments
>file2 command2 --with --even --more arguments
>file3 command3 big line | command4 big too # wrong

My solution so far, apart from putting the redirection at the end, is using a function:
cmd3() { command3 $1 $2 $3 | command4 $4 $5 $6; }
>file3 cmd3 ${args[@]}

But maybe there's a more straight forward way?

For what it's worth, I find the redirection first, especially for output redirection, very confusing and hard to read. Your code, your preference, of course, but don't assume that others will also find it more readable even if it is possible.

Alternatively to functions, you could put the redirection on a separate line (with the backslash at the end if the first line to mark continuation), if you find that clearer. Anyway, you need to quote those expansions, cmd3 "${args[@]}" and command3 "$1" "$2" "$3".

I agree with terdon.  People will expect to find output redirection to the right of the command, not to the left.  When it's on the left, it will be confusing.  You have to balance the helpfulness of having the redirection on the left of a long command+args against the un-helpfulness of the confusion it will create.  This can be solved in other ways, though.  For example, write a comment line explaining why the redirection looks strange.  Or put the long command+args into a shell function with a short name and call it as func-name > file1 (with comment explaining the function).

Maybe:
( > file exec; cmd1 | cmd2 )

That said, Bash documentation says:

The [...] redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within
a simple command or may follow a command.

So any straight-forward ways are ruled out as the freedom to place redirections anywhere applies only to simple commands.

Somehow, preoending the redirection to exec looks even odder than doing it with a "normal" command...

That documentation line explains the syntax error, which is nice. I like this solution. The redirect before exec looks weird to me too but it doesn't matter as long as it works. exec >file; would work too, as long as the filename is not lost at the end of the (very long) line.

You could use eval:
>output eval 'foo | bar'

Or switch to zsh which allows:
>output { foo | bar; }

And even:
>output {foo | bar}

Those also work with the rc shell (the should have been successor of the Bourne-shell from plan9, Unix v10) from which zsh did get some inspiration.
With zsh, that also works for anonymous functions, with both the (){...} args and function {...} args syntaxes:
>output (){local var; foo $1 | bar $2} X Y

In any case, note that long lines can always be broken down.
foo | bar | baz > output

Can be written:
foo | # comments can also go here
  bar |
  # and here
  baz > output

Or:
foo | ba\
r | baz \
> output


I use | at end of line a lot. The beauty of this is that you can put comments in the middle of a pipeline.

@OleTange good point, I've added a demo of that.
